# Create smaller map view using Google Maps SDK Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-maps

I am wondering if anyone knows how to code a smaller window of Google Maps using their SDK in Swift?  The examples given result in a view that takes up the entire screen.  I want mine to be smaller to allow for other content.  Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CIGk.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSUO3.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please include the relevant line from the example, and probably link to the example as well?

Comment: Here is the example.  I uploaded what I had in the links above.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#add_a_map

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to create a view in your storyboard and set its class to GMSMapView, then declare an IBOutlet for the view of the type GMSMapView I named it myMapView (dont forget to link it) then you add this lines to your ViewController inside the viewDidLoad function:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(4.739001, longitude: -74.059616, zoom: 17)
let myGSMMap = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
myMapView = myGSMMap
```

Answer (score 0):

Create ContainerView instead of UIView, then add the map to the embedded view controller of container view. It should be work