# Swift 4 GoogleMaps add UIToolBar / make map "smaller" to fit other UI elements

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

Perhaps this is the exact same question as [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801121/create-smaller-map-view-using-google-maps-sdk-swift)

However, I need a more **step by step** / **tutorial** type answer.

I want to add a UIToolBar item at the top of my GoogleMap.  But the map takes up the entire view.  I've searched everywhere and every tutorial, but I can't figure this very simple thing out.  If part of the solution is adding a new swift file and placing the 'GMSMap' code there and then changing the original view controller class - that is fine, but I need just a tiny bit more ***step by step***

I've tried play with "withFrame", however that does not seem to help

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    var mapView:GMSMapView!
    var latitude:Double = 0
    var longitude:Double = 0
    var zoom:Float = 15
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var userLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setup simple mapview and camera

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, zoom: zoom)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        self.mapView.delegate = self
```

## **UPDATE**

Things are somewhat better, but there is still a nagging problem.
[I have a new repo here](https://github.com/bbookman/MapApp)

I added two UIViews inside the default View:UIView and added constraints.  The 'Map View is type GMSMapView. And I added a view at the top of the scene 'Button View' with a button.  Now my UI looks like I want it.

I also created an IBOutlet for GMSMapView and wired it to 'Map View'.

### HOWEVER

The map that is displayed is ignoring the latitude and longitude variables.  No matter what I set them to, I always see France and other parts of Western Europe.  In the example below, I'm using coordinates for San Francisco

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView:GMSMapView!
    var latitude:Double = 37.7749
    var longitude:Double = 122.4194
    var zoom:Float = 12

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, zoom: zoom)
        let myGSMMap = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView = myGSMMap
        self.mapView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Images for clarity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/csh8q.jpg . (the green in the upper portion of the screen is the UIView, and below it you will see the map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write below code in your `viewWillAppear()`

```
Self.mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, zoom: zoom)
```

It will move your map camera according to `latitude` and `longitude`.

And remove what your write-in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Thanks, however the exact same problem occurs.  Note I mentioned there are two UIViews.  One UIView with custom class GSMMapView.  Moving the code from viewDidLoad to viewWillApper did nothing.  I am still getting a generic map, rather than what is specified in latitude and longitude. @Faysal

Comment: I think this is what is happening, but i don't know why or how to work through it...  "The map should be instantiated via the convenience constructor [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:camera:]. It may also be created with the default **[[GMSMapView alloc] initWithFrame:] method (wherein its camera will be set to a default location)"**

Comment: Note that fussing with the CGRect also has zero effect.  I'm almost positive I'm getting a generic GMSMapView. This does nothing  **let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y:30, width: 200, height: 200)
        let myGSMMap = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: rect, camera: camera)
        mapView = myGSMMap**

Comment: Don't move your code just remove it from viewDidLoad and write my code in viewWillAppear actually I downloaded your repo and it's working when I write my code in viewWillAppear and commented your from viewDidLoad ()

Comment: For more clarity please add an marker and if your want then I will update your code in issue part of your&#39;s code repo

Comment: You are very kind mayank.  I'm not sure what you mean by add a marker.  However I will invite you to my repo if you give me your git user name.  https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/

Comment: Mayank, i did try your suggestion.  What I get is a Google map inside the view like i want, but the map itself is all blue.  No land :).  Feel free to push all my code to your own version of the repo on git if you want.

Comment: User name:- Iamak0515

Comment: mayank, i have added you as a collaberator.  https://github.com/bbookman/MapApp/invitations

Comment: I fixed it myself.    I can't believe how easy and dumb this is.  The longitude was wrong.  It is that simple.  The longitude is not 122.4194.  It is -122.4194 . NEGATIVE!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://www.ryanwright.me/cookbook/ios/obj-c/maps/gmap/subview. It might be helpful. You have a detailed explanation given.

Comment: Unfortunately, that page did not help me.  First, there is some critical steps missing or I'm not understanding.  I created a new project in objective C and copied all the code.  However, I don't follow the comment `//self.mapContainerView is an IBOutlet UIView* that is connected 
//to a UIView on the storyboard`

For swift 4 (and also ob-c), I can't seem to make a UIView an IBOutlet.