# Read data from Firebase using Swift4 - has childByAutoId upper node

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I know I've got to 'observe', but exactly what the code should look like is driving me insane!  The app adds a latitude and longitude to Firebase with a childByAutoId upper node and I want to read those.

getData() is intended to read all locations.

**Swift 4**

```
/**Data looks like this
-locations
-- L44dslhfhdslhf 
-----latitude: "90.8883"
-----longitude: "46.9732"
**/

var ref:DatabaseReference!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("locations")
    }

func addLocation(){
        let location = ["latitude": latitudeInput.text!,
                        "longitude": longitudeInput.text!,
            ] as [String : Any]
        ref.childByAutoId().setValue(location)
    }
func getData(){
```

/** NOTHING BELOW WORKS, AND I HAVE TRIED TONS OF DIFFERENT APPROACHES **/

```
        self.ref.child(<WHAT HERE>).observe(.value, with { (snapshot)} in

        if let snapshot =  snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]{
                for snap in snapshot {
                    if let data = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                        let lat = data["latitude"]
                        let long = data["longitude"]
                        print(lat as Any)
                        print(long as Any)
                       }//end if
                }//end for
            }//end if
        }//end ref
    }//end getData
```

Comment: in `getData` do you want to read all the locations ?

Comment: Did you check this?  https://github.com/firebase/geofire

Comment: Yes, i want to read all locations,thanks for asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is simple use directly location observer. as you are adding locations with autoid so you don't need any child key over there

and also your code

`self.ref.child(<WHAT HERE>).observe(.value, with { (snapshot)} in`

should be

`self.ref.observeSingleEvent(.value, with { (snapshot)} in`

you can observe single event for value. so it will read all the current value once with

after that

`self.ref.observe(.childAdded, with { (snapshot)} in`  (call when child will added to locations)

Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: Perfect!  This fixed things.  Any chance you can take a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48456186/swift-4-googlemaps-add-uitoolbar-make-map-smaller-to-fit-other-ui-elements/48457095#48457095).  Marking this one resolved!

Comment: @BruceBookman Glad that solution worked for you !! , Have a great day !